# Create an ESDT swap on the MultiversX blockchain

Tags: swap, multiversx

I've planned to do a project on the MultiversX Blockchain with an ESDT token.

On the platform, users should swap EGLD to the ESDT, but I can't see any [doc](https://docs.multiversx.com/developers/tutorials/your-first-dapp/) on this.

Does someone have an idea about this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can look over this sample contract:

https://github.com/multiversx/mx-sdk-rs/blob/master/contracts/core/wegld-swap/src/wegld.rs

This is what you need, maybe adapt the ratio (in the sample contract is 1:1).